# How to put in webservice with alarm manager in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, alarmmanager

I don't have any idea on how i will put data from webservice and at the same time it will work in alarm manager to send data every set of time. I know how to put data from webservice but with alarm manager I don't have any idea. I try the process of putting data from webservice but it takes an error because the class has extends BroadcastReceiver. This is how i put in the webservice.

```
public void passdata(View View){
String a = name.getText().toString();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

if(a != null){
params.put("name", a);
WebService(params);
}
}

public void WebService(RequestParams params) {
        progressDialog.show();

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://192.168.8.100:8080/taxisafe3/webService/login", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                progressDialog.hide();
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                    if (object.getBoolean("status")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                        gotoHome();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username or Password is incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
                progressDialog.hide();

                if (statusCode == 404) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error Occured! (No Internet Connection)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

How can i do this putting of data in webservice with alarm manager? So that I can send data from the WebService every minute for example. Please help.

UPDATED from Joseph Answer:

```
    public class Web extends IntentService {
    String msg = "aw";
    public Web(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("message", msg);
        WebService(params);

        Intent in = new Intent(Web.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Web.this, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, pendingIntent);
    }
    public void WebService(RequestParams params) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://192.168.254.105:8080/taxisafe3/webService/emergency", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                    if (object.getBoolean("status")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Emergency Sent to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Emergency not Sent to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {

                if (statusCode == 404) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error Occured! (No Internet Connection)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Receiver Class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {        
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Web.class);
        context.startService(i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer. In AlarmReceiver initialize the Request params then remove the parameters inside the WebService then put the message coming from another class. This is the code.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
//This is the message come from another class
String msg = bundle.getString("mess");

//check if the message is not null
        if(PatternChecker.isNotNull(msg)) {
            params.put("message",msg);
            Webservice();
        }
}

WebService method here to perform the sending data to the webservice.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Service` that should be called when the alarm goes off. The `Service` should include all the needed code for calling your web service.
In order to reschedule the call to the web service, you can use [`AlarmManager.setRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method.

So, extends an `IntentService` (it is an implementation of Service class, that simplify your work) in this way:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

  public DownloadService () {
      super("DownloadService");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      callWS(); //this method can execute your AsyncTask for calling web service, or anything you want
  }
}
```

Now declare a `BroadcastReceiver` that should receive the

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent arg1) {
        Intent i = new Intent(c, DownloadService.class);
        c.startService(i);     
    }
}
```

Set the `AlarmManager` for repeating the operation. (Call this just once)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateReceiver.class);

PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis()+30000, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR * 2, alarmIntent);
```

In the above example, a call to the web service will be done after 30 seconds, and each e hours in the future.

**NOTE**: if your device is reboot, your alarm is cancelled, so if you want recreate it you should create a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and allow you to call the above code for setting the repeating alarm.

Comment: sir where will i put the Alarm manager? and where will i put the params.put that i have in the code above before calling the web service?

Comment: You can pass the parameters in the intent, in this way: `intent.putExtra("EXTRA_PARAMS", params);`
**Note:** your class RequestParams should implement `Parcelable` interface)

Comment: the alarm manager will be set in DownloadService? in calling the webservice?

Comment: The AlarmManager should be called when you want start the service. For example when you click a button, or the first time you start your app.

Comment: sir i updated the question and put the code that i created based on your suggestion. I am correct? because when i try to run it. It still doesnt send the data from the server. I can;t see new reports from database that i have.